# How to keep submenu opened after page load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, menu, load

I have almost done my work and my client ask for keeping submenu opened when user click the item in the menu and also set active color. The idea is better orientation when user actualy is. In React App it wouldn't be problem, cuz whole app works like single page. In this case i've decided use only HTML/JS as my challenge.

Is it even possible somehow keep menu opened/open again menu when new page is loaded please?

I tried make from this app something like single page app by some tutorials like "load paghe without refresh" etc, but nothing worked.

**menu**

```
<div class="menu">
          <div class="item">
            <a class="sub-btn">
              Matice
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/zakladni-operace.html"
                id="matice/zakladni-operace"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Základní operace
              </a>
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/hodnosti.html"
                id="matice/hodnosti"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Hodnost
              </a>
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/determinanty.html"
                id="matice/determinanty"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Determinanty
              </a>
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/inverzni-matice.html"
                id="matice/inverzni-matice"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Inverzní matice
              </a>
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/maticove-rovnice.html"
                id="matice/maticove-rovnice"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Maticové rovnice
              </a>
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/vlastni-cisla-a-vektory.html"
                id="matice/vlastni-cisla-a-vektory"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Vlastní čísla a vektory
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get `window.location.href` on load of your page and add style classes depending on conditionally with something like
`<div class="<%= 'yourStyleClass' if @url== 'urURL' %>">` to set active color

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to call the page. But that doesn't sound like what you want. An alternative way in javascript would be to get the current window.location.href when the page loads, then inject a class name into the relevant node, and have the css for that class make it visible and highlighted.

If you're using a library like jQuery this shouldn't be too hard to achieve.